# How to do multi-class binding using vue.js with click event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-directives

Have a healthy days. The problem I'm trying to solve is conceptually very simple. I'm new to working with Vue.js and I have some perception issues with the `class binding`. I am preparing a mini project to understand the subject. There are color buttons at the top and an area at the bottom that changes color when these buttons are clicked.
[HTML side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1780.png)

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
        data(){
          return {
            color_palette : [
              {
                index : 1,
                id : "red",
                css_class : "red-box"
              },
              {
                index : 2,
                id : "blue",
                css_class : "blue-box"
              },
              {
                index : 3,
                id : "green",
                css_class : "green-box"
              },
              {
                index : 4,
                id : "yellow",
                css_class : "yellow-box"
              }
            ],
            
          }
        },
        
        
      }).mount('#app');
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: start;
}

.css--class--app .css--palette {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.css--class--app .css--palette li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.css--class--app .result-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #18bf71;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<header>CSS Class App</header>
    <div class="container css--class--app" id="app">
      <div class="card text-center">
        <ul class="css--palette text-center">
          <li v-for="color in color_palette" ></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="result-box" ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In such a case, what kind of `click` event is required to define buttons? I dont want to copy and paste the answers. I just want a explanation to understand concept of `class binding` with multiple `click` event.

Comment: Could you make yourself clear please? Do you want to add multiple classes by one click event or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `activeClass` property and bind it to the result box `class`.  An important thing to notice is that you may use `class` and `:class` simultaneously.  Both are applied:

```html
<div class="result-box" :class="activeClass"></div>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    activeClass: ''
  }
}
```

On click, change the `activeClass`:

```html
@click="activeClass = color.css_class"
```

Also bind the classes to the buttons.  Putting it all together:

```html
<li v-for="color in color_palette"
    :class="color.css_class"
    @click="activeClass = color.css_class"></li>
```

You may want to reduce the specificity of your default classes or you'll run into a little complexity when trying to give precedence to the bound class (or you can just use `!important`).  Here's a demo:

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  data(){
    return {
      activeClass: '',
      color_palette : [
        {
          index : 1,
          id : "red",
          css_class : "red-box"
        },
        {
          index : 2,
          id : "blue",
          css_class : "blue-box"
        },
        {
          index : 3,
          id : "green",
          css_class : "green-box"
        },
        {
          index : 4,
          id : "yellow",
          css_class : "yellow-box"
        }
      ],
    }
  }
});
app.mount("#app");
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: start;
}

.css--class--app .css--palette {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.css--class--app .css--palette li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.css--class--app .result-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #18bf71;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.css--class--app .red-box {
  background: red !important;
}
.css--class--app .blue-box {
  background: blue !important;
}
.css--class--app .green-box {
  background: green !important;
}
.css--class--app .yellow-box {
  background: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" class="">
  <header>CSS Class App</header>
  <div class="container css--class--app" id="app">
    <div class="card text-center">
      <ul class="css--palette text-center">
        <li v-for="color in color_palette"
            :class="color.css_class"
            @click="activeClass = color.css_class"></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="result-box" :class="activeClass"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```